# Using [] operator with a linked list?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create a Linked List in C++ that works similar to how Lists work in Python on the user end. One feature I'm trying to implement is using the [] operator to reference the value of a node, allowing you to easily access it.

Here is the member function I wrote for it, which at the moment just acts as a getter:

```
int operator [] (int index) {
    if (index >= length) { // length is a member variable
        throw out_of_range("");
    }

    IntNode* current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        if (current->index == index) {
            return current->value;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to make it so the [] operator can be used as both a getter and a setter?

For example on the user side a getter would be used like:

```
int someInt = myList[1];
```

And a setter would be used like:

```
myList[1] = 67;
```

This, of course, is assuming `myList` has an 'element' at index 1. 
Also, `myList` is a reference to a `List` object (Not a pointer).

*Note: I plan to make this structure work via a template at some point. Right now I just want it to work with integers.*

Comment: Have a look at [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). There is a const and a non-const version. (The former returns `const T&` and is `const`, the latter returns `T&`.) As the non-const version provides a reference, this can be used for write access (to element).

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a mutable, and a const version. If the mutable version returns a reference, then you can assign to it.

```
int& operator [] (int index);
const int operator [] (int index) const;
```

I'm not going to say this is a *good* idea though. Attempting to treat a linked list as an array, especially as presented above, is not going to be very efficient.

Comment: Would having the node's value be private effect this since the reference would go out of scope on the user's end?

Comment: No. It's a linked list. The value that is being referred to is in the list (and therefore is not a stack variable, but a variable with a fixed memory location).